# How to tie different data in sql with same post_id

Tags: sql

Below is How this Table data look a like

```
Post_id  |  P_key  | P_value
10       |  F_name | Amar
10       | l_name  | Arya
10       | country | India
11       | F_name  | Karan
11       | l_name  | Roy
11       | country | Nepal
```

And I want to display same post_id detail in one row like this

```
f_name  |  L_name | Country
Amar    | Arya    | India
Karan   | Roy     | Nepal
```

So can you please suggest me SQL query for it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option using `conditional aggregation`:

```
select max(case when p_key = 'f_name' then p_value end) as f_name,
       max(case when p_key = 'l_name' then p_value end) as l_name,
       max(case when p_key = 'country' then p_value end) as country,
       post_id
from yourtable
group by post_id
```

This will return a single row for each `post_id`.

Comment: but when I'm running this code it showing Null value

Comment: @AmarArya -- please explain further.  If you have `null` values returned, then you don't have corresponding rows for that criteria for that post.  This is a generic version of a table `pivot`.

Comment: I'm including an image of that table in answer field. please have a look.

Comment: @AmarArya -- consider creating a sqlfiddle.com with your table structure, sample data and expected results.  As is, it's still difficult why this answer doesn't solve your problem...

Answer (score 0):

This is the image how table and column looks

[Please see image][1]
     [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ppkK.png

Here miglad_firstname and all these values of  `meta_key` has repeated but     `meta_value` is different.